# OpenAPI models with multiple discriminators not showing in Redocly

Tags: openapi

I'm trying to use OpenAPI v3 to define models with polymorphism. I've tried the following model definitions and, while they appear to be successfully processed by the Redocly linter, the API documentation generated by Redocly seems to fail to properly document the models.

Here are the OpenAPI document:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  version: 0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
  title: Pet Adaption API
  description: |
    Adopt a pet!
servers:
  - url: 'https://example/pet/api/v1'
    description: Pet Adaption API

paths:
  /pet_adaptions:
    post:
      summary: Mark a pet for adaption
      description: Mark a pet for adaption
      operationId: adopt
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetType'
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: The pet was marked for adaption
        400:
          description: The payload was poorly formatted.
        500:
          description: Unexpected server error.

components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          description: What goes on their collar.

    PetType:
      type: object
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
        mapping:
          CAT: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
          DOG: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
          
    Dog:
      type: object
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/LargeDog'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SmallDog'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: size
        mapping:
          large: '#/components/schemas/LargeDog'
          small: '#/components/schemas/SmallDog'
      required:
        - type
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          description: The type of pet. Always set to `DOG`
        
        
    LargeDog:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      required:
        - size
        - floofFactor
      properties:
        size:
          type: string
          description: The size of dog. Always set to `large`
        floofFactor:
          type: integer
          description: Floofiness of large dog (1 - 10)
        
    SmallDog:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      required:
        - type
        - size
        - yapFactor
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          description: The type of pet. Always set to `DOG`
        size:
          type: string
          description: The size of dog. Always set to `small`
        yapFactor:
          type: number
          description: Yapiness of small dog (0 - 1.0)
        
    Cat:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      required:
        - type
        - colour
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          description: The type of pet. Always set to `CAT`
        colour:
          type: string
          description: Colour if the cat's coat
```

And the following should all be valid examples:

LargeDog

```
{
  "name": "Rex",
  "type": "DOG",
  "size": "large",
  "floofFactor": 3
}
```

SmallDog

```
{
  "name": "Skip",
  "type": "DOG",
  "size": "small",
  "yapFactor": 0.9
}
```

Cat

```
{
  "name": "Mr Tinkles",
  "type": "CAT",
  "colour": "black"
}
```

The API documentation renders just fine if looking at the `CAT` example but not when looking at the `DOG` example.

Have I created an invalid OpenAPI v3 document or is this likely just an issue with Redocly?

[image: CAT]
[image: DOG]

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass the discriminator inside `size` property.

```
Dog:
      type: object
      required:
        - type
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          description: The type of pet. Always set to `DOG`
        size:
          type: string
          description: The type of pet. Always set to `DOG`
          discriminator:
            propertyName: size
            mapping:
              large: '#/components/schemas/LargeDog'
              small: '#/components/schemas/SmallDog'
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/LargeDog'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SmallDog'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsbc9.png)

Comment: Hmm, that seems to turn `size` into an object with the fields of `LargeDog` or `SmallDog` i.e. `{
"type": "DOG",
"size": {
"size": "string",
"floofFactor": 0,
"name": "string"
}
}`